# xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName - Multiple same tag names, get only one from certain parent?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to parse different XML file for certain information, but in the file's there are multiples of the same tag name, but the amount of them may vary on file to file basis, meaning I can't just add what number tag it is, I would like to base it off of it's parents tag, so only that certain parent/tag will be parsed.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       myFunction(this);
   }
};
request.open("GET", "test.xml", true)
request.send();
function myFunction(xml) {
   var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
   var test = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SerialNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
};
```

I've read about Xpath but can't seem to get it to work in my code.

The example is there are multiple SerialNumber tags, but I would like test to only become the SerialNumber node value that is under the parent "Storage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this for `myFunction`:

```js
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var resultset = xmlDoc.evaluate('//Storage/SerialNumber', xmlDoc);
    var nodes = [];
    var node;

    while (node !== null) {
        node = resultset.iterateNext();
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    // Do what you need to here.
    console.log(nodes);

    // For example, to get the first result's text contents:
    console.log(nodes[0].textContent);
};
```

That uses an XPath query to find all `SerialNumber` elements that are children of `Storage` nodes in the retrieved XML document.

If you have a spec that says there will only ever be one `Storage > SerialNumber` parent / child combo in the document, it's worth checking the length of the resulting array and throwing an error when it isn't one.

Comment: It's possible there could be more then one SerialNumber Parent/Child combo, but when I run that code, it's logging "[object Element],"

Comment: That's what I'd expect if there's just one in the document. You should be able to get whatever you want from the element objects in the array. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I'm still fairly new at this, so if I'm missing something obvious I apologize. The array nodes only has one thing since it's only one document, but the value is [object Element], not what is under the SerialNumber tag in the XML File, I see it's finding the correct object, but not the correct value?

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated the example with how to get the actual text content of the tag. I apologize for not reading your question more carefully.

Comment: Glad to be of service.